# maximising or optimising a function in SAS (not PROC NLP or IML)

Tags: optimization, sas

Is there a proc or method to maximise a function in SAS eg a likelihood. I know of proc nlp and iml but my version of SAS 9.4 doesn't have them

Comment: What SAS Product do you have? Do you have SAS/STAT or SAS/OR?

Comment: thanks Draycut, I don't think I have SAS/OR as I don't seem to have proc nlp (and I think thats in SAS/OR) - pretty sure I have SAS/STAT as I have proc genmod, proc mixed etc and all the usual SAS stats procedures

Comment: Are you trying to maximize/optimize a function in general, or just trying to find maximum likelihood? Generalized optimization problems are all solved with PROC OPTMODEL, and IML will help with general matrix functions. Maximum likelihood can be solved in a few different ways.

Comment: many thanks, Stu, its not really maximising a likelihood I need though my problem is similar in that it is estimating parameters to maximise a quantity based on data - as an alterative to logistic regression "maximimum likelihood" estimates I want to find estimates - a weighted sum of predictors - that maximises the AUC. proc optmodel sounds a good option, thanks, I will see if it works for this and if my SAS actually has it.